# Firing CDI-Events within a thread

Tags: multithreading, events, vaadin, cdi, wildfly

Within an Vaadin application I am planning to implement an asynchronous result-overview for a method.

The result overview contains a table for possible results. These results should generate while a backend-method is running asynchronous in a thread. Communication between the backend and frontend of the application is planned with using CDI-Events (information for the result will be in the CDI-Event).

I already achieved to fire CDI-Events, put them into the result-table and display the table after the method is finished. But when I execute the method within a thread (so the view is displayed and events get inserted instead of waiting to see the complete table), my CDI-Events won't fire (or get received).

Is there any way to work this out? I read about receiving CDI-Events asynchronous ([blog entry](http://www.next-presso.com/2014/06/you-think-you-know-everything-about-cdi-events-think-again/)), but I did not find anything about firing events within a thread...

WildFly 10.0.1.Final, Java 8, Java-EE 7 and Vaadin 7.6.6.

Thread, which should fire CDI-Events:

```
public class Executer implements Runnable{ 

  @Override
  public void run(){
    // Here will be the backend-method invocation for firing CDI-Events

    // CDI-Dummy-Event - Does not fire properly. receiveStatusEvent() does not invoke
    BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
    beanManager.fireEvent(new ResultEvent("Result event example"));
  }

}
```

Bean which receives CDI-Events

```
public class EventReceiver implements LoggingProvider{

  public EventReceiver(){

  }

  public void receiveStatusEvent(@Observes ResultEvent event) {
     this.info("Event received: " + event.toString());
  }

}
```

Starting the thread with help from ManagedExecutorService

```
public void executeAsynchBackendMethod(){

  // CDI-Dummy-Event works - receiveStatusEvent() invokes correctly
  BeanManager beanManager = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
  beanManager.fireEvent(new ResultEvent("Result event example"));

  /* The following alternative starts a thread, but the events, which are fired in the run() method, do not take any action in the receiveStatusEvent() method */

  // Getting managedExecuterService 
  this.managedExecuterService = (ManagedExecutorService) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService");

  // Getting Instance of executer-Runnable (for injecting the backend-service afterwards)
  Instance<Executer> executerInstance = CDI.current().select(Executer.class);
  Executer executer = executerInstance.get();

  // Start thread
  this.managedExecuterService.submit(executer);
}
```

Comment: If you want to access Vaadin components from a different thread, you need the [UI access method](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html#advanced.push.running) and some type of asynchronous update to browser like Vaadin Push or [poll](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+polling). Otherwise changes to UI are not send to client until the next request happens (e.g. button click).

Comment: Thank you for this advice!
I know that accessing the UI is achieved through .access()... But AFAIC this method should be used, when a concret UI change will be implemented (like adding one result to my result table).

It provides me a access to the UI of the application.  I already tried it with .access(), but my UI was blocked, until the method finished... So for executing thecomplex backend-method I choose to create a thread with my managedExecuterService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CDI 1.2 and below, events are strictly synchronous. In CDI 2.0 there is already an implemented version of asynchronous events (in Weld) but I suppose you are stuck with 1.2.

That means (as the blog post you read suggests), you can make use of the infamous EJBs.

As for why CDI does not work in this case - I would say this is all thread-bound. In other words in that given thread where you fire the event you have no observer to be triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answere. I did a work-around and annotated the backend-method with `@Asynchronous & @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` instead of starting the method in a thread. Now I can avoid the disadvantages of CDI 1.2 and get events while invoking the method asynchronous... **Works like a charm**!